# Как узнать за какое время выполняется шаг в отладке VSCode C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, отладка

Не могу понять или хотя бы получить намек о том как можно **замерить время выполнения шага в отладке**. В Visual Studio 2019 это делалось через средства диагностики, но в vscode не смог найти и намека(ни расширение, ни что либо еще).

Comment: Интересно, какая польза от этого? Производительность бессмысленно измерять в отладочном режиме. А вообще копать наверное в сторону профилирования процессора.

Comment: можно воспользоваться банальным stopwatch но в целом как сказал аэпот - в режиме отладки это на 100% бесполезное занятие